# Adding pre-defined Office Ribbon button to custom ribbon in Visual Ribbon Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, ribbon, office-2010

I know how to add existing Office Ribbon items or groups to my custom ribbon using XML (*using `idMso` tags*) but how do I do this using the Visual Studio **Ribbon (*Visual Designer*)** technique?

Would really rather not have to build the entire thing using XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Ribbon Designer**, you can access the [`ControlId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbontab.controlid.aspx) which points to the `idMSO` used in **Ribbon UI XML**. More specifically, [`ControlId.OfficeId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribboncontrolid.officeid.aspx) represents the `idMSO` property that contains the [specific Office control identifier](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6627).

```cs
tools.Ribbon.RibbonTab tab = Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonTab();
tab.ControlId.OfficeId = "TabNewMailMessage";
```

Comment: This is code, not part of the designer. I don't see ControlId or idMso anywhere in the Properties of a group or button. It looks like this: imgur.com/NINLk

Comment: I agree with @Chris. The shown approach is available only for `tab` controls in the Ribbon Designer, not for groups or button..